# Live A/B website performance testing

Tags: google-chrome, performance, css

Is there a way in Chrome web dev tools, to alter the site (CSS for example) and measure / compare the loading performance before and after the edits ?

If I change the CSS, as soon as I reload the page (in the Network tab) it reloads the original CSS - obviously.

**I would need to somehow make the changes permanent, or save the altered state in order to compare it to the original.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I perform A/B website testing?

> If I change the CSS, as soon as I reload the page (in the Network tab) it reloads the original CSS - obviously.

You need to perform your A/B testing in a different way.

Below are some recommendations.

---

#### The Ultimate Guide To A/B Testing

> **Create Your First A/B Test**
>
> Once you’ve decided what to test, the next step, of course, is to
>   select a tool for the job. If you want a free basic tool and don’t
>   mind fiddling with HTML and JavaScript, go with [Google Website
>   Optimizer](http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer).
>
> If you want an easier alternative with extra features, go with [Visual
>   Website Optimizer](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/) (disclaimer: my start-up).
>
> Other options are available, which I discuss at the end of this post.
>   Setting up the core test is more or less similar for all tools, so we
>   can discuss it while remaining tool-agnostic.
>
> You can set up an A/B test in one of two ways:
>
> 1. Replace the element to be tested before the page loads
>
>    - If you are testing a single element on a Web page—say, the sign-up button—then you’ll need to create variations of that button (in HTML)
>        in your testing tool.
>    - When the test is live, the A/B tool will randomly replace the original button on the page with one of the variations before
>        displaying the page to the visitor.
> 2. Redirect to another page
>
>    - If you want to A/B test an entire page—say, a green theme vs. a red theme—then you’ll need to create and upload a new page on your
>        website.
>    - For example, if your home page is http://www.example.com/index.html, then you’ll need to create a
>        variation located at http://www.example.com/index1.html. When the test
>        runs, your tool will redirect some visitors to one of your alternate
>        URLs.

Source [The Ultimate Guide To A/B Testing](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/the-ultimate-guide-to-a-b-testing/)

Comment: We use VWO here, it highlighted some interesting layout changes.